# how to print a list from json document

Tags: javascript, html, json, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to print my data from list.json file

```
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET","list.json",false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    var list = xmlhttp.responseText;
```

this is my list.Json

```
{

"p1": {
    "name":"fruit song",
    "cat":"learning",
    "lan":"eng",
    "ur":"abc1"
},
"p2": {
    "name":"eting sugar",
    "cat":"random",
    "lan":"eng",
    "ur":"abc2"
},
"p3": {
    "name":"salgira ka din",
    "cat":"birthday",
    "lan":"urdu",
    "ur":"abc3"
},
"p4": {
    "name":"twinkle twinkle",
    "cat":"random",
    "lan":"eng",
    "ur":"abc4"
},
"p5": {
    "name":"abc song",
    "cat":"learning",
    "lan":"eng",
    "ur":"abc5"
}
```

}

and i am getting data like

```
obj = JSON.parse(list);
$scope.n =obj.p1.name;
$scope.c =obj.p1.cat;
$scope.l =obj.p1.lan;
$scope.u =obj.p1.ur;
```

this works fine and shows data in alert($scope.n);

i want to print this json file in html with cards like

p1  name : {{n}}    category : {{c}}   language :  {{l}}

p2  name : {{n}}    category : {{c}}   language :  {{l}}

inside the list.json there will be 50+ P1 type records.

can anyone tell me the code to print all the record in html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use AngularJS's ng-repeat, like

```
<div>
  <p ng-repeat="(key, val) in obj">{{key}} name: {{val.name}} category : {{val.cat }} language : {{val.lan}}</p>
</div>
```

For future references, use AngularJS documentation: [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

Comment: this ng-repeat worked for me.. Thank you for your help/

Answer (score 0):

so my html is

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items"   item="item" ng-click="model.itemValue = item" >
<div class = "row" style="background: url(img/4.jpg) no-repeat center;background- 
size:cover;">
<div class = "col"><h3>{{name}} :)</h3></div>
<div class = "col col-60"><h3>{{email}}</h3></div>
<div class = "col"><h3><button class="button button-calm button rdm">PLAY</button> 
</h3></div>
</div>
</li>
```

and my controller is

```
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlhttp.open("GET","Ulist.json",false);
 xmlhttp.send();
 var list = xmlhttp.responseText;
 obj = JSON.parse(list);

 $scope.data = {};

 $scope.model = {};

 $scope.items = obj;
```

this worked for me